# Testing with enzyme and mocha -- "Unexpected token import"

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, enzyme

I'm trying to run the Enzyme/Mocha example project at https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-mocha. I cloned the project off of Github and ran `npm install`. When I ran `mocha` without making any other changes to the project, this is the output I received:

```
/Projects/enzyme-example-mocha/test/Foo-test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:511:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

My `node --version` is `v6.1.0` and my `mocha --version` is `2.4.5`.

How do I get this project to transpile into something Node/Mocha can run? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `npm run test`? I saw the `test` script in `package.json` (in the `"scripts"` section), ran it, and it worked the first time.

The difference with `npm run test` vs just `mocha` is the former includes the file `test/.setup.js`, which requires `babel-register` and executes it, which is essentially what you were saying about missing a transpile step.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the preset 2 setting in your .babelrc.

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`

Add the following line to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-2","react","es2015"]
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed. The project already includes a `.babelrc` file which has the airbnb preset, which in turn requires react as well as the minimum es2015 support.

Comment: @TylerCollier that does not include the stage-2-preset

Comment: Understood. But why add `stage-2`? It's unnecessary. You can run `npm run test` without `stage-2`.